# ASP.NET MVC - One table cascade delete

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, database, cascading-deletes

I have an application showing a directory tree. It looks like I have catalogs displayed. The user selects a directory, presses the delete button and the directory and subdirectories should be removed.

Here is my Node class:

```
    public class Node
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public String Name { get; set; }

        public Node Parent { get; set; }
        public int? ParentId { get; set; }
    }
```

Here is my Button

```
<button type="button" style="display:none;" id="delete_node" class="btn btn-danger" data-base-url="@Url.Action("Delete","Home")">
            Delete node
        </button>
```

Jquery method which runs Delete Action:

```
        $('#delete_node').on('click', function (e) {


            var urlToDelete = $(this).data('base-url') + '/' + SelectedId;

            $.post(urlToDelete, function () {
                location.reload();
            });
        });
```

And Delete Action:

```
        [HttpPost]
        public HttpStatusCodeResult Delete(int id)
        {
            Node nodeInDb = _context.NodeEntities.Single(n => n.Id == id);

            _context.NodeEntities.Remove(nodeInDb);
            _context.SaveChanges();

            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK);

        }
```

All is fine, but when the catalog which I want to delete is empty. When catalog have subdirectories and I pressed Delete Button appears a error

> SqlException: The DELETE statement conflicted with the SAME TABLE REFERENCE constraint "FK_dbo.Nodes_dbo.Nodes_Parent_Id". The conflict occurred in database "TreeDB", table "dbo.Nodes", column 'ParentId'.
>   The statement has been terminated.

It seems that catalogs do not delete in the cascade way. How can I turn on this option?

[**Sample records in the database**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rVQWG.png) <-----------------

Answer (score 0):

I think Entity was create a foreign key with `public Node Parent { get; set; }`.

Comment: It's true, but I want to also delete the rows which the parentInt does not exist

Comment: See database, Document is parent of Pop,Rock, Music. You need delete childrens or change our parentInt

Comment: Does exists a way to automatically delete a rows where Parent Id does not exist?

Answer (score 0):

I'v just made a method to remove a directory and subdirectiories, but I think is better way to do this.

```
        private void Remove(Node node)
        {

            var listOfNodes = _context.NodeEntities.Where(a => a.ParentId == node.Id);
            if (listOfNodes != null)
                foreach (var node3 in listOfNodes)
                    Remove(node3);

            _context.NodeEntities.Remove(node);
        }
```